# Setting the Managed Object Context on a StoryBoard TabBar - Table view Controller with embedded Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, core-data, storyboard

I'm trying to use CoreData with Storyboard on a TabBar - NavigationController - TableViewController configuration.

When trying to assign the Managed Object Context  to the TableViewController I get

```
[UITabBarController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

If I understand correctly, the problem is that I'm not getting the TableViewController instance. I've tried many things but I don't seem to be getting anywhere.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fixit using Matthijs Hollemans tutorial on raywenderlich.com.

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
MyViewController *controller = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```